# I want to connect a Docker Superset container to an existing external MySQL database

Tags: docker, apache-superset

I am trying to add an existing MySQL database as a source database to a docker container running Apache Superset. The MySQL database that I am trying to add is not running in a docker container. It's an existing MySQL database running on a Windows machine.

I've added `mysqlclient==1.4.6` to `requirements.txt`. The error message seems to indicate that the driver is installed.

I've used `mysql://user:password@127.0.0.1:3306/database_name` and `mysql://user:password@localhost:3306/database_name`

The error I get is:

> "ERROR: Connection failed, please check your connection settings."

I am using image: `apache / 'incubator-superset' v. 0.36.0`

Are there any settings or config that needs to be changed to be able to communicate to an external database from within a running docker container?

Comment: This should do the trick: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach

Answer (score 2):

So I figured it out. For Windows, run ipconfig (maybe ifconfig linux, mac) in terminal/powershell and check what ip address docker ethernet port is using (listed as WSL), let's say ip is: 172.x(x).x(x).x(x). Then configure connection string with ip address on docker ethernet port as follows: 'mysql://user:password@172.x(x).x(x).x(x):3306/database_name'.

Follow-up question if anybody knows: How can I connect my docker container running apache/superset to another server/ip address on my local network running a MySQL server? In other words I want to connect the apache/superset app that is running on my computer in a docker container, to another computer on my local network that is running a MySQL server. The MySQL sever is not in a docker container.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the steps of [this blog](https://preset.io/blog/2020-05-18-install-db-drivers/) can help.

If your mysql is in other docker it it is not 127.0.0.1 and in addition if you don't want the requirements to be updated every time that you git pull a new docker, it is better to use the requirements-local.txt

Comment: Thanks! I read the blog post you linked to but no success. I'm on a Windows machine and the instructions in the linked post are for Linux and Mac only. And just to clarify, only the superset app is in a docker container. The mysql database I am trying to connect is on localhost and/or the network and it is not in a docker container.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that but your MySQL has to have external IP that you can access from your Supserset Machine. First do a telnet to see if you can listen from port 3306 to that machine and if you can Supserset should work with very similar URI that you have.